# i have not changed POM file But getting Error in CICD

Tags: wso2

## I am New to WSO2 ,please have a look at pom file i am facing error on line 15.
Error is

## Error line 15: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:

## Regards
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the POM? or point to the guide which you follow?

Comment: how i can share , infact when i past  pom file its give me formatting error